# How to install Entity Enrichment libraries in Marklogic 8?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to use Entity Enrichment pipeline for document conversion.  I have the following XQuery in the Query Console for a DB that has Content processing installed:

```
let $myxml := <node>George Washington never visited Norway. If he had a Social Security number, it might be 000-00-0001.
              </node> 
return cts:entity-highlight($myxml, 
          element { fn:replace($cts:entity-type, ":", "-") } 
                  { $cts:text })
```

...which results in the following error:

```
"Entity enrichment libraries not installed for host"
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

cts:entity-enrich() and cts:entity-highlight() are no longer available, so that piece of code will not work in MarkLogic 8.

There are a number of ways to do entity enrichment of documents in MarkLogic, such as

1. install a third-party entity extraction tool such as Smartlogic or PoolParty or Temis
2. If you know how to define your entities in terms of queries, write a reverse query for each entity type and use cts:highlight() to markup those entities.

For more information, drop me a note at stephen dot buxton at marklogic dot com

Answer (score 1):

For MarkLogic 6, you can add entity enrichment libraries for your database by going to the MarkLogic console at 8001, choosing Configure, then Databases.  Select your database and Content Processing beneath the database in the tree.  Choose Install to install content processing libraries.

For MarkLogic 8, `cts:entity-highlight` is no longer supported.  [Entity Enrichment Pipelines](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/entity) can be created, and `cts:highlight` can be used for highlighting, e.g.:

```
cts:highlight($myxml, "Norway", <b>{ fn:replace($cts:text, "-", ":") }</b>)
```

...where the second parameter can be a query and the third parameter can include any markup.

It may also be useful to take a look at the MarkLogic [Search Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for response. I have already installed the content processing under database and it shows the entity-enrichment pipeline enabled. Even Search Dev guide also does not provide any step to install this library. I am trying below piece of code in query console for the DB which has Content processing installed -                  let $myxml := <node>George Washington never visited Norway. If he had a Social Security number, it might be 000-00-0001.</node>
return cts:entity-highlight($myxml, 
   element { fn:replace($cts:entity-type, ":", "-") } { $cts:text })

Comment: Can you tell what am I missing here.

Comment: The answer has been update after your comment. It seems to be no longer available..